# Why is this 'for' loop going too long?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is a small code snippet that essentially tries to use a `for` loop to find all multiples of `a = 3` that are less than 1000 and sum them together. For some reason the final value of `mult` is 2997, which is not within `range(max)`. Thus, I'm confused as to why the final value of `mult` isn't 999 and why the `for` loop even executes after `mult` *does* hit a value of 999.

```
a = 3             
max = 999   
sum = 0     #cumulative sum of 'a' multiples
mult = 0    #current multiple of 'a'
k = 1       #counter variable

# --- Find all multiples of 'a' that are below 1000 ---
for mult in range(max):
    mult = a*k
    print(mult)
    sum = sum + mult
    k+=1
```

Also, it seems that changing the value of `a` directly affects how high `mult` will get before the loop is finished. More precisely, I've found that the final value of `mult` is equal to `a*max`, and I cannot think of a reason why this would be.

***Edit: Nevermind, I realized that I intended to use a `while` loop but made the mistake of implementing a `for` loop instead. Sorry about this. Thank you to everyone who took the time to answer me.***

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other programming languages, `for` loops in Python strictly iterate over the given values.

I. e., with `for mult in range(max):`, `range()` defines what values should be assigned to `mult` on every loop run. It is not affected by any values you assign to `mult` later.

This concept is called iteration. `range(max)` returns an object which gives on every loop run the next value. In Python 2, this was just a list containing these values, in Python 3, it is an object which calculates the values "on demand".

Answer (score 0):

It actually doesn't. It goes for exactly 999 times. The last output however is 2997, but as you can see in the output it always increases by 3. This is due to you reassigning mult to `a*k`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `mult` is defined as the product of `a` (a constant equal 3) and `k`, initially equal to 1, incremented 998 times by 1 every time the loop passes, i.e. it is 999 at the end and `3 * 999 = 2997` in total.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, then you want to print all the values between 0 and max and sum them right?
then the following code should help you.

```
for mult in range(max+1):
    if mult % a == 0:
        print mult
        sum = sum + mult
print sum
```